# Electric potential inside a charged sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

My textbook says:

"For a point p outside the sphere at distance r from the center of the sphere, the potential at p is: $$Ve = \frac{kQ }{r}$$

On the surface of the sphere the potential is: $$Ve = \frac{kQ }{R}$$ Where R is the radius.

But at any point inside the sphere, the electric potential is constant and has the same value as the potential at the surface."

Why is the last point true? Judging from the potential on the surface of the sphere, the charges in this case are supposed to be at the center of the sphere (distance R). Why isn't Ve getting bigger as point P moves toward the center when it's inside the sphere? How can it be constant and equal to the potential at the surface as the distance between the charges and the point decreases?

Comment: Do you know that the electric field inside the sphere is zero ? Can you proceed further ?

Comment: No, I don't know that the electric field inside the sphere is zero. But if it is zero and my book says it is equal to the potential at the surface, then the electric field at the surface of the sphere is also zero?

Comment: If your sphere is conducting , then the field is discontinuous at the surface ( means it's not defined at the surface) . I am talking about field **inside** the surface .

Comment: However if your sphere is non-conducting , then field is defined at surface which is $KQ/R^2$ .

Comment: We are dealing with electrostatics and calculating field in an electrostatic equilibrium.The field is zero and potential difference between surface and any point inside is zero because if it weren't, then charges would move inside which is contradictory to the condition of our static equilibrium.

Comment: @Abbas that makes sense! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This might help you to understand :https://youtu.be/MnZD5Fi0VJM